# how to return function or promise based on call site?

Tags: javascript, promise

I would like to know if you have some clean way for creating a function that works when called by itself returning a promise, and returns a function when chained in a `.then`.

example:

```
// returns a promise. use to start chains: 
// eg: wait(400).then(...)
const wait_p = (t) => new Promise( resolve =>  setTimeout( resolve, t) );

// returns a function: use inside .then(): 
// eg: $get('whatever').then(wait_f(300))
const wait_f = (t) => () => wait_p(t)
```

what's the cleanest way to have both wait_p and wait_f  merged in a single `wait()` function?

```
//hypotetically:
const put = (x) => () => console.log(x) 
wait(1000)
  .then(put('one'))
  .then(wait(1000))
  .then(put('two'))
```

Comment: You can return a resolved promise with `Promise.resolve(wait_p(t))`, although you should wrap in a `Promise`, as `wait_p` can fail.

Comment: Also, a function with polymorphic return type would be a surprise to its callers

Comment: No doubts that it's confusing and not a good practice. But still ...

Comment: You could add a second argument to `wait()` that says whether it should return immediately or return a promise.

Answer (score 2):

Having a schizophrenic function is probably not a great idea, even if you could figure out how to do it. Choose one and use it. Either:

```
wait_f(1000)().then(wait_f(1000))...
```

or

```
wait_p(1000).then(() => wait_p(1000))...
```

Personally I often use a function like your `wait_f`, but I rarely find myself wanting to use it to start a promise chain.

Comment: "*schizophrenic function*" - LOL, but very fitting!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could return a function with a `then` method:

```js
const wait = t => {
  var p = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,t));
  var func = () => p;
  func.then = (...args) => p.then(...args);
  return func;
}
wait(400).then(() => console.log('Hello'))
Promise.resolve().then(wait(500)).then(() => console.log('World'))
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the timeout won't even begin until you've actually called `.then()` on the result of `wait()`. So you couldn't just store the result of `wait()` to a variable and expect it to be a pending promise. The other problem with this is that calling `.then()` on that variable multiple times would result in multiple timeouts being set and none of them would resolve at the same time.

Comment: Beautiful. Works as expected.